# Refreshing QGIS project after updating MS Access Database?

Tags: qgis, ms-access

I already connected the MS Access DB to QGIS via ODBC. Moreover, I applied the tool "create point layer from table" and I got all points from the DB (longitude/latitude coordinates) on my map. And after updating the DB I clicked the Refresh  Button in QGIS, but nothing happened.

Only after I break the odbc connection and create a new one, I see the results in QGIS.

Can I change this?Is it not working automated?

Comment: Does there exist any solution?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what version of QGIS are you running?

Comment: Hello, its version 3.4.11. I need the refreshing because i have to update the the access db every because it contains information about vessels (coordinates) and I have to display them in QGIS. In other words, the map has to be up to date. thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible with another database (postgresql)?